# Angular Material 2 Included Jquery Code In Component Not Working

Tags: angular, materialize

I set up a project with [angular2-materialize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize). The navigation on the webpage should be handled by the `HamburgerMenuComponent`.

So I started to include this sidebar:  [SideNav - Materialize](http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html#!)

It is working fine when I'm manually inserting `$(".button-collapse").sideNav();` in the browser-console.
But I can't figure out how to include it to the `HamburgerMenuComponent`.

This is what I tried so far but it is not working:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hamburger-menu',
  templateUrl: './hamburger-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hamburger-menu.component.css']
})
export class HamburgerMenuComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
  }
}
```

> AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_jquery**(...).sideNav is not a function

Comment: Is it a compile error or a browser console error ?

Comment: @trichetriche console error

Answer (score 1):

Try editing your `vendor.ts` *(newer Angular-cli uses `lib.ts` instead, but is the same)* and then recompile:

```
// jQuery
declare let jQuery: any;

// Dependencies
window['jQuery'] = require('jquery');
window['$'] = window['jQuery'];
import 'jquery-ui-npm/jquery-ui.min.js'
```

And in your component ad this after all imports:

```
declare let $: any;
```